# Is there is a Cocoa framework for windows or a interface builder for windows like we have in mac?

Tags: cocoa

Is there is a Cocoa framework for windows or a interface builder for windows like we have in mac?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might look into [Cocotron](http://www.cocotron.org/),

> an open source project which aims to implement a cross-platform Objective-C API similar to that described by Apple Inc.'s Cocoa documentation. This includes the AppKit, Foundation, Objective-C runtime and support APIs such as CoreGraphics and CoreFoundation.
>
> …
>
> The general goal is to provide complete support on any viable platform, the project is intended to be as portable as possible. However, most of the work at this time is focused on providing support for Microsoft Windows. In particular the NT based versions, 2000 up to Vista.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can install Objective-c on windows and you can install some of the old the NextStep APIs but you can't get the Cocoa Frameworks or other Apple APIs.